# Send a FILE with AJAX, plain Javascript: nothing is send. POST data is empty

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is my HTML code:

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
<input type="button" value="Send the file" onclick="inviaFileAJAX()" />
```

This is my AJAX function:

```
function inviaFileAJAX() 
{
    if(!document.getElementById("file").value) 
    {
        alert("No file selected");
        return false;
    }

    var file = document.getElementById("file");
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file.files[0]);
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    else 
    {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && `xmlhttp.status == 200)` 
        {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "invia_file.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    xmlhttp.send(formData);
}
```

If in php i write

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

In the alert in the AJAX function:

```
alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

I get undefined reference because the old:

```
$_FILES["file"]["name"]
```

isn't found. The POST array is empty. Where is the problem?

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/#toc-send-formdata

Answer (score -1):

The most common method is a 'fake ajax' method that consists in create a lying iframe in the page and direct the form target to it.

ex:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" target="myInvisibleFrame" method="post">
<input type="file" name="myfile"/>
<button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>

<iframe id="myInvisibleFrame" style="display: none;" onload="alert('complete!');"></iframe>
```